# Why is the symplectic group defined with a skew-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

The symplectic group is defined as the group of matrices $X$ such that $X^T J X = J$ for some fixed skew-symmetric matrix $J$.

Why does $J$ have to be skew-symmetric? Verifying the group axioms doesn't depend on the skew-symmetry of $J$, and any group defined the same way except with an arbitrary matrix $J$ is well-defined, in that it's always non-empty since the identity satisfies the condition trivially.

So why do we specify that $J$ should be skew-symmetric?

Comment: $J$ should at least be invertible. Of course, other choices give you interesting groups as well, like the orthogonal groups or the indefinite orthogonal groups. If you have a bilinear form then it's natural to study the matrices that preserve it.

Comment: Oh okay. So it's not necessary for $J$ to be skew-symmetric? I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing.

Comment: The symplectic group uses a skew-symmetric matrix $J$. You can get different groups with different $J$